# looking for a way to speed up the loading time of my page without compromising the web page

Tags: php

I have made a webpage for a livestreaming layout, is there a way to speed up the loading process? because it loads a bit to slow to my standards, it takes about 5-10 seconds to load, wich is way to slow, i rewrote a lot of the code, to make the methods more universal, but the process still takes up way to long, perhaps the problem is with the first method (value_in) but i don't realy know for sure.

```
Hello and welcome to the Livestream page for the broken diamond community here you can find all our content creator's livestream pages to watch them game. you can chat with other members and even them! We always welcome new followers and will love to hear about suggestions for games, in game tips and all those opinions we know you have to share!

    <?php
    header('Refresh: 60');
    define('ELEMENT_CONTENT_ONLY', true);
    define('ELEMENT_PRESERVE_TAGS', false);

    function value_in($element_name, $xml, $content_only = true) 
    {
        if ($xml == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        $found = preg_match('#<'.$element_name.'(?:\s+[^>]+)?>(.*?)'.'</'.$element_name.'>#s', $xml, $matches);
        if ($found != false) 
        {
            if ($content_only) 
            {
                return $matches[1];  //ignore the enclosing tags
            }
           else 
           {
                return $matches[0];  //return the full pattern match
            }
        }
        // No match found: return false.
        return false;
    }

    loadpage();
    function loadpage()
    {
          echo "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width: 95%\" >";
          echo "<tr class=\"info-row\" bgcolor=#252525 style=\"color:white;  height: 15px;\">";
          echo "<td style=\"width: 14%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Preview</b></td>";
          echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Live</b></td>";
          echo "<td style=\"width: 36%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Stream</b></td>";
          echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Viewers</b></td>";
          echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Time online</b></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          addrow(107473,10,"Osuryn","Osuryn is streaming random games live",false);
          addrow(210320,28,"Dennojj","Dennojj is streaming PS3 games",true);
          echo "</table>";
    }

    function addrow($streamID, $streamPage , $streamName , $streamSlogan, $odd)
    {
         if ($odd)
         {
                echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#A7A7A7>";
         }
         else
         {
                echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#BFBFBF>";
         }
         echo "<td style=\"width: 14%;\"><img src=\"http://img.hw.own3d.tv/live/live_tn_".$streamID."_.jpg\" style=\"height: 72px;\" \></td>";
         echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br><b>".getLiveStatus($streamID)."</b></td>";
         echo "<td style=\"width: 36%; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 6px;\">";
         echo "<div><br><a href=\"http://brokendiamond.org/?q=node/$streamPage\">$streamName</a></div>";
         echo "<div style=\"padding-top: 6px; font-size: 11px;\">$streamSlogan</div>";
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br>".getLiveViews($streamID)."</td>";
         echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br>".getOnTime($streamID)." minutes online</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
    }

    function getLiveStatus($streamID)
    {
        $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$streamID;
        $arg = '240';

        $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);

        if (preg_match("/true/",$response, $result)) 
        {
            $streamStatus="Live";
        } 
        else 
        {
          $streamStatus="Offline";
        }
        return $streamStatus;
    }

    function getLiveViews($StreamID)
    {
        $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$StreamID;
        $arg = '240';

        $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);

        $viewStatus =value_in('liveViewers', $response) + "";

        return $viewStatus;
    }

    function getOnTime($StreamID)
    {
        $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$StreamID;
        $arg = '240';

        $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);

        $onStatus =value_in('LiveDuration', $response) + "";

        return $onStatus;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Well, what part is slow? Is it the server response? Bandwidth? Browser?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, 5 to 10 seconds is pretty slow. But it probably has nothing to do with your own code. Calling the external API several times is the part that is slowing it down so much.

If the calls you are making to the external webservice are known beforehand you should try and have a background process poll every other minute or so and cache the results. Then your actual script can access the cached results which will be a lot faster.

Comment: i'm quite new to php and all xP so i do not have a clue how to start doing that, the cashe and stuff, so i'd love some help, if you have the time for it ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Use a caching mechanism and a Timestamp timeout. That was your data stays updated and your server isn't making a ton of requests all the time.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that, is there a way you could help me with it, maybe send a link where i can start from?

Answer (score 1):

How often does the data changes? if it does not change often, have a scheduled task (cron) that generates and save the file ss html so the browsers will just load the html.

Comment: it changes from the second a member begins to livestream, then it changes once every viewer joins, or leaves.

Comment: How timely would the data have to be? will it cause problem if the data is five minutes behind? if no just have the data be cached and update it using a cron job that runs every five minutes.

Comment: i'll look in to that, i currently have it set up so it refreshes every 5 mins, and just the div of the table, so it currently works like that so once my website is finished i'll revisit this problem, thanks a lot for your response ;)

Comment: What i would do would be to benchmark all the api calls and try to find the offending code. then bugger the owner to check.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing external API's. You're at the mercy of the other website.